# Create multiple rows in table with live search

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to do a live check and create a row in a table for each result. What i do is i do a check with jquery when the user is filling in a result in a textfield.

The textfield looks like this:

```
<input name="teamNaam" type="text" class="personeelField" id="teamNaam" onkeyup="return check_teamnaam();"/>
```

And the jquery is this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Loading').hide();
    });

    function wait(msecs) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        var cur = start
        while (cur - start < msecs) {
            cur = new Date().getTime();
        }
    }

    function check_teamnaam() {

        var teamNaam = $("#teamNaam").val();
        if (teamNaam.length > 2) {
            $('#Loading').show();
            $.post("checkVriendenTeam.php", {
                teamNaam: $('#teamNaam').val(),
            }, function (response) {
                //$('#Info').fadeOut();
                // $('#Loading').hide();
                var reactie = response;
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(reactie);
                console.log(obj.Coureur);

                if (reactie == "Bezet") {
                    //fffkdf
                } else {



                    $('#Info tr').has('td').remove();
                    $('#Info tr:last').after('<tr class="tabeltitel" height="30"><td width="5%">#</td><td width="29%" class="tabeltitel">' + response.Teamnaam + '</td><td width="23%" class="tabeltitel">' + response.Manager + '</td><td width="24%" class="tabeltitel">Vrienden worden</td></tr>');
                }

            });
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

It is checking the 'checkVriendenTeam.php' and it gets back a result. The result looks like this:

```
[{"Teamnaam":"test"},{"Teamnaam":"test2"},{"Teamnaam":"test3"}]
```

I make this result with a php code:

```
if($_REQUEST)
{
    $teamNaam   = $_REQUEST['teamNaam'];
    $query = "select * from spelers where Teamnaam  LIKE '".strtolower($teamNaam)."%'";
    $results = mysql_query( $query) or die('ok');

    if(mysql_num_rows(@$results) > 0) // not available
    {   $response = array();
        while($inhoud = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

        $response[]['Teamnaam'] = $inhoud['Teamnaam'];

        }
        $jsonData = json_encode($response); 
        echo $jsonData;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no result';
    }   
}
```

But it will only create one row without any data (undefined). So what do i need to do to get 3 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering you have the right response , to get three rows.. you have to use `jquery.each` loop

try this

```
    ....
    else{
       $('#Info tr').has('td').remove();
       $.each(obj ,function(i,v){  <------ here
         $('#Info tr:last').after('<tr class="tabeltitel" height="30"><td width="5%">#</td><td width="29%" class="tabeltitel">' + v.Teamnaam + '</td><td width="23%" class="tabeltitel">' + v.Manager + '</td><td width="24%" class="tabeltitel">Vrienden worden</td></tr>');
       });
     }
```

**NOTE:** not sure why your are using `v.Manager` there since there is no manager in your obejct... either you have to send it thorugh your php code, or remove that...

Comment: this code is working thanks. What part of the code for the v.manager can i remove?

Comment: if u check your code... dynamically added `<tr>` you will see `response.Teamnaam` and `response.Manager`.. so here the manager is not there in the object so u might end up gettin undefined....

Answer (score 0):

this line is incorrect:

```
$('#Info tr:last').after('<tr class="tabeltitel" height="30"><td width="5%">#</td><td width="29%" class="tabeltitel">' + response.Teamnaam + '</td><td width="23%" class="tabeltitel">' + response.Manager + '</td><td width="24%" class="tabeltitel">Vrienden worden</td></tr>');
```

To get the team names, use:

```
obj[0].Teamnaam
obj[1].Teamnaam
// and so on....
```

This is because, you are parting the JSON and setting it as 'obj'. So obj contains the array of objects from given by your PHP script.